# “my email ID has changed” vs “my emil ID is/has been changed”

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, present-tense, participles

I want to ask one thing. Sometimes we hear people say

> my email ID has changed.

As per my understanding present perfect tenses need a subject which is missing above.
I find these sentences little bit weird because I think we should have subject in using present perfect if it is not passive one.

I think we should say

> 1. my email ID is changed
>      or
> 2. my email ID has been changed.

Please help me out to use present perfect effectively, the present perfect tense make me confuse.

Comment: It's not clear to me what argument you're trying to make. Are you suggesting that other verb tenses *don't* need a subject? Or are you saying that the other verb tenses *are* passive while the first isn't? (I don't see anything wrong with your first sentence, and I'm trying to figure out why it concerns you but the other sentences don't.)

Comment: You really need to ask this kind of question on the English Language Learners site.

Comment: @Billy It's not in the passive voice--that's exactly what's troubling OP.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a matter of the perfect construction but of two different senses of the verb.

*Change* is what is sometimes called a “labile” verb†. Labile verbs are used in both transitive/agentive and intransitive/stative senses: for instance, we say both

•   *Water is boiling on the stove* (intransitive/stative—we’re describing the state of the water)
•   *I’ll boil water for tea* (transitive/agentive—we’re describing my action)

*Change* works the same way: we say both

•   *Her hairstyle has changed* and
•   *She has changed her hairstyle*.

---

† <sub>Other terms for this phenomenon are “middle voice” and “mediopassive voice”—I used them myself until I was introduced to “labile”—but these have somewhat different senses in their core uses, and should probably be avoided. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/413122/24489).</sub>